# How does a Glass user sign up to receive specific service Timeline Items?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I'm trying to figure out how a Glass user signs up to receive specific Timeline Items? I create the Timeline Items to push and the Glassware/Mirror rest services, how will the Glass user sign up for the services I created.  Is there a Glass app subscription store?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: How users authorize your software and how they discover it.

**Authorization Process**: Glass users subscribe to Glassware using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/glass/authorization). Specifically, by granting you the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline` scope, they provide your service permissions to read and write to their timeline.

You can see this flow described in [API Usage Stories](https://developers.google.com/glass/stories#cat_facts) page in this sequence diagram:

[image: How users subscribe to a service with OAuth 2.0]

**Discovery**: This has not yet ben announced.

Users need to be directed to the URL that initiates your OAuth 2.0 flow to authorize. How users will find that URL is something that hasn't been answered yet. Don't stress too much about this during the developer preview. Instead focus on the features of the Mirror API.

Comment: Thank you Jenny.  I can't wait for you to see the application I'm building!

Comment: I wrote down some of my learnings with developing Glassware, [my blog writeup](http://gregcullenfg.blogspot.com/2013/05/google-glass-designing-future.html).  Hope it helps others get a leg up.